# Apache2 does not work with SSL on Debian 1

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, ssl

I need help, because I get 503 Service Unavailable on my website using HTTPS! (Apache/2.4.56 (Debian) Server at mydomain.com Port 443) I followed a tutorial, because I never had worked before with certbot. This is the Tutorial (https://voiceoverit.de/blog/allgemein/mailcow-mit-reverse-proxy-auf-debian-ubuntu-installieren/938/) and I have done it until the point I have to download Mailcow and install it (Mailcow herunterladen und installieren). The connection is secure and the certificate is valid is shown on Google Chrome. My Destination is to configure a https reverse proxy with a docker/mailcow container.

Here my Configuration File:

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain.com

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
   ServerName mydomain.com
   ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
   ServerAlias autodiscover.*
   ServerAlias autoconfig.*
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^autoconfig. [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}# [L,NE,R=permanent]
   RewriteRule ^ /autoconfig.php [PT]
   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyAddHeaders On
   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http"
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.com [OR]
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =autodiscover.* [OR]
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =autoconfig.*
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName mydomain.com
   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyAddHeaders On
   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
   Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
 </VirtualHost>
```

I have tested the resources, but they are not overloaded. Also I reboot the Server.
My Destination is to configure a https reverse proxy with a docker/mailcow container.